# Como incluir secuencia en WebService Restful

Tags: xml, webservice, oracle-11g, restful

Tengo creada una base de datos en `Oracle 11G`, donde hay una secuencia para hacer los registros autoincrementables:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE S_CATEGORIA MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE;
```

Mediante un webservice necesito guardar un nuevo registro a la tabla Categoria, en esto no hay problema sin utilizar la secuencia.

Este es la estructura que utilizo para enviar:

```
<categorias>
 <categoriaId>1</categoriaId> //ID de la categoria, aqui debo utilizar la secuencia
 <descripcion>Aceites</descripcion> //Descripcion
</categorias>
```

Como podría enviar los datos para que considere utilizar la secuencia que está en la BD??

Gracias por su ayuda...
Saludos_!

Comment: Te esta dando algún error porque si tienes configurada las secuencia debe ser automático

Comment: @RaulCacacho Si mando el xml sin ID, en la base de datos se registra con un 0 y si lo mando con s_categorias.nextval me da error 400:
`descriptionThe request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

Comment: El webservice lo tienes en java o en que lenguaje lo tienes?

Comment: Yo veo que es por la forma que mapeasta las tablas

Comment: Está en java, el mapeo generado por netbeans

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75866/discussion-between-raul-cacacho-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mayoria de veces debes de hacer ajustes a los `Entity` que se generan los mapeos en netbeans porque no agregan campos que son **autoincrementables** o cuando tenemos una tabla donde guadarmos nuestra secuencia esa información debemos de agregrala con **anotaciones** te dejo dos ejemplos:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORIAS" , schema = "tutorial")
@SequenceGenerator(
name="secuenciaCategoria",
sequenceName = "S_CATEGORIA",
initialValue = 1, 
allocationSize = 10
)
public class Categorias {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "secuenciaCategoria")
private Long id;
private String name; 
}
```

Este otro ejemplo es cuando usas una tabla con las secuencias, el nombre de la tabla es `SGU_SECUENCIAS`

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID_ACCION", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "ACCION_GEN")
@TableGenerator(name = "S_CATEGORIA", table = "SGU_SECUENCIAS",
        pkColumnName = "NOMBRE", valueColumnName = "VALOR",
        pkColumnValue = "SguAccion", allocationSize = 1)

private Integer idAccion;
```

Comment: Excelente, funcionó a la primera, gracias crack!